# Integrate Hubspot tracking page view in Angular 9

Tags: javascript, angular, hubspot

I am trying to track page views in Angular 9 and I am using Hubspot for doing it.
Is there any method to integrate Hubspot tracking page view in Angular 9 project?
What dependency could I use to get things easier? Any advice will be helpfull?